Does puppeteer v21.6.1 supports openEuler?
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: ['--disable-gpu']
    });
 await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 120000 });

      const buffer = await page.pdf({
        format: 'a4',
        printBackground: true,
        scale: 0.7,
        margin: {left: '0.5cm', top: '1cm', right: '0.5cm', bottom: '1cm' }
      });

chrome: linux-119.0.6045.105
meet an error:
TargetCloseError: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Target closed
at CallbackRegistry.clear (/usr/share/nginx/server/node-exam-cloud-pdf/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:85:36)
at CdpCDPSession._onClosed (/usr/share/nginx/server/node-exam-cloud-pdf/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/CDPSession.js:113:25)
at #onClose (/usr/share/nginx/server/node-exam-cloud-pdf/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Connection.js:168:21)
at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nginx/server/node-exam-cloud-pdf/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/NodeWebSocketTransport.js:57:30)
at callListener (/usr/share/nginx/server/node-exam-cloud-pdf/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:290:14)
at WebSocket.onClose (/usr/share/nginx/server/node-exam-cloud-pdf/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:220:9)
at WebSocket.emit (node:events:519:28)
at WebSocket.emitClose (/usr/share/nginx/server/node-exam-cloud-pdf/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:264:10)
at Socket.socketOnClose (/usr/share/nginx/server/node-exam-cloud-pdf/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1283:15)
at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28) {
cause: ProtocolError
at <instance_members_initializer> (/usr/share/nginx/server/node-exam-cloud-pdf/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:96:14)
at new Callback (/usr/share/nginx/server/node-exam-cloud-pdf/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:100:16)
at CallbackRegistry.create (/usr/share/nginx/server/node-exam-cloud-pdf/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:32:26)
at Connection._rawSend (/usr/share/nginx/server/node-exam-cloud-pdf/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Connection.js:91:26)
at CdpCDPSession.send (/usr/share/nginx/server/node-exam-cloud-pdf/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/CDPSession.js:78:33)
at navigate (/usr/share/nginx/server/node-exam-cloud-pdf/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Frame.js:164:51)
at CdpFrame.goto (/usr/share/nginx/server/node-exam-cloud-pdf/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Frame.js:142:17)
at CdpFrame.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nginx/server/node-exam-cloud-pdf/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/util/decorators.js:108:27)
at CdpPage.goto 

how to resolve it? if not support，where I can find the offical answer?
